# Convert Invalid Json into valid json android?

Tags: java, json, string

I want to convert jnvalid JSON data into valid JSON data. I have JSON like this below. Is there any logic to change it using Java?

```
 {
    name: date,
    order: 1,
    required: true,
    type: date,
    placeholder: Expense Date
}
```

I want valid JSON data formatted as below:

```
{
    "name": "date",
    "order": "1",
    "required": "true",
    "type": "date",
    "placeholder": "Expense Date"
 }
```

Comment: order is `Number` or `String`? and also required is `Boolean`?

Comment: @amir110 String only sir

Comment: Show us what you've done, this isn't a code delivery service

Comment: You could do it quite easily using String.split() and a StringBuilder.

Comment: Iterate thru your file and add the missing ' " '.
1. After '{'
2. Before ':'
3. After ':'
4. Before ','
5. After ','
6. Before '}'

Comment: @Shane How can i achieve using StringBuilder can you help me sir...i tried but i cannot achieve

Comment: Show us what you tried @Mariyappan

Comment: @JuliusHörger Sir i am using **firebase firestore**  i am getting invalid json responce so i want to convert into valid jsonresponce

Comment: @Mariyappan if `firebase` is the case then you are printing it to see result then it won't shoe quotes around , why you thinks it's invalid response specially from firebase

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh i have asked before...Please check it sir..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791325/how-to-get-json-response-from-firebase-firestore?noredirect=1#comment82546067_47791325

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh when i try to extract i not able to get data sir..due do invalid json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to do it for you as you haven't provided any code to what you have done but I will guide you on how to do it.
Iterate over the file or the string whatever you have it on, line by line. 
Then instantiate a string builder to keep appending the valid JSON to.
append the first quote to the string builder, then use line.split(':') on a single line to get an array with the 1st half of the line and the second half. Then append the splitLine[0] (1st half) onto the string builder, append the colon, append the 2nd half of the line splitLine[1] and finally append the last quote and the comma. Now do this for every line and you will have valid JSON.

Here is a working version of what I explained above.

```
String inputString = "name: date, order: 1, required: true, type: date, placeholder: Expense Date";
StringBuilder validJson = new StringBuilder();
validJson.append("{");
String[] lineByLine =  inputString.split(",");
for(int i =0; i< lineByLine.length; i++){
    String[] lineSplit = lineByLine[i].split(":");
    validJson.append('"').append(lineSplit[0].trim()).append('"').append(":").append('"').append(lineSplit[1].trim()).append('"').append(i==lineByLine.length-1?"}":",");
}
String finishedJSON = validJson.toString();
System.out.println(finishedJSON);
```

The bit at the end may look a little confusing

```
i==lineByLine.length-1?"}":","
```

But what it is doing is checking if it's the last line of JSON close it with a bracket, otherwise place a comma ready for the next attribute

Comment: If it's all in one string, split the entire string by a comma, then iterate over given array to do it line by line

Comment: `name: date, order: 1, required: true, type: date, placeholder: Expense Date` this will be dynamic..how can split and store sir..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791325/how-to-get-json-response-from-firebase-firestore?noredirect=1#comment82546067_47791325 Please check sir..you can understand my problem

Comment: I can not achieve using  `splitLine[0]`

Comment: `for(String keyvalue : thatBigDynamicString.split(",")) { //no split keyvalue on ':' ; }`

Comment: did you make a variable called splitLine from splitting by ":"?

Comment: @shane I tried some differed way sir......just i started using split...please help me sir in this case...i try i will update my status

Comment: I'm at work at the moment, I will come back to look at this when I finish. If you still haven't figured it out I will code it for you. @Mariyappan

Comment: @Shane No problem sir...i will try update my code within 1 hr..if i am not please help me sir...

Comment: @Mariyappan I have updated my answer to give the code

Answer (score 1):

you can use replaceAll and regex:

```
String str = "{ name: date, order: 1, required: true, type: date, placeholder: Expense Date }";

/*remove '{' and '}' for trim*/
String trim = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).trim();

/* x:y => "x":y */
trim = trim.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\\s*\\:)", "\\\"$1\\\"$2");

/* "x":y => "x":"y" */
trim = trim.replaceAll("(\\:\\s*)([a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+)", "$1\\\"$2\\\"");

str = '{' + trim + '}';
```

Comment: let me check,,i will getback you sir

Answer (score -1):

it can be done by splitting string by “:”

Comment: How can i split sir,,,,i think it's not possible

Comment: possible first of all split the string by ‘,’. Then split every string by ‘:’ and then take the second value of the array

Comment: `name: date,
    order: 1,
    required: true,
    type: date,
    placeholder: Expense Date` this will be dynamic..how can split and store sir..

Comment: `String[] arr=string.split(“,”); for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){ String[] innerarr=arr[i].split(“:”); Log.e(“++parsed_value”,innerarr[1]);}`

Comment: I will try sir4

Comment: let me know after try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161117/discussion-between-mariyappan-and-md-ibrahim-khalil).